# vim color scheme: changing keyword color

Tags: vim, colors

I really like my current vim color scheme (`/colors/desert.vim`).

The syntax highlighting is great except for the color of certain keywords.
For example, in ruby files (`.rb`), I dislike how it highlights `def` and `end`.
In java files (`.java`), it's the `import` keyword.

The color is a dark purple that clashes against my background.

How do I change this color? I can edit the `desert.vim` file, but am having trouble finding the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the full list of things that are highlighted by typing `:hi` (short for highlight).

You can also look in `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/syntax/<filetype>.vim`, e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/syntax/ruby.vim`, or your computer's equivalent.

For Java includes, try either:

```
:hi link Include NONE
```

or

```
:hi PreProc NONE
```

For Ruby `do` `end`, try either:

```
:hi link rubyControl NONE
```

or

```
:hi Statement NONE
```

You can put whichever one works in your `~/.vimrc` to make it persistent.

If you want to change the color to something else, see the [:highlight documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) for more details.

Comment: For persistence, I'd rather suggest putting custom language-specific highlight colors in ~/.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim . This will leave the default color scheme unchanged and will keep ~/.vimrc minimal, holding only general settings.

Comment: The line ended up being: `hi PreProc  ctermfg=5` (and all other places with `ctermfg=5`), which I changed to `ctermfg=7`.